# Google maps marker clustering for Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I am using Google maps plugin in my Flutter application & I need to group markers basically need to use marker clustering like shown in attached URL[Google maps marker clusters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/images/clustering-custom-icon.png). I didn't find any marker clustering library/plugin for Flutter Google maps.

Can you please suggest any plugin for this? Or suggest a way ro implement a custom plugin for this?

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by clustering?

Comment: Please check attached image URL

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this new package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/clustering_google_maps

You can perhaps try this package to do the clustering by yourself:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/k_means_cluster